# Cardinals definable using ordinal arithmetics

Tags: cardinals, ordinals

Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal.

$\kappa$ is stable under ordinal addition $+$, ordinal multiplication $.$ and ordinal exponentiation $e: (a,b) \mapsto a^b$, so $\mathcal{K} = (\kappa,+,.,e,\in)$ is a model theoritic structure.

**a) Is the set of cardinals $< \kappa$ first order definable in $\mathcal{K}$?**

**b) Which cardinals $< \kappa$ are first order definable in $\mathcal{K}$?**

Note that if $\{|\lambda| \ | \ \lambda \in \kappa\}$ is definable then so are all $\aleph_{\alpha}, \alpha < 2.\omega_0$ (provided they are in $\lambda$), and you can probably go much further.

Not too much however, for one can only define countably many cardinals, so there is a least undefinable cardinal $\leq \aleph_{\omega_1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Note that $\mathcal K =(\kappa, +, e, \in)$ is absolute between transitive models of ZFC. Thus any collapse below $\kappa$ demonstrates that the set of cardinals below $\kappa$ cannot be first order definable in $\mathcal K$ if $\kappa > \omega_1$.

b) Sorry, I'm not sure how to prove my initial claim that the answer is $\omega + 1$. I will add to this answer in a moment.

---

Actually, the situation is easier: If $\kappa$ is uncountable, collapse $\kappa$ to $\omega_1$. As $(\omega_1,+,e,\in)$ cannot define uncountable cardinals, absoluteness yields the result.

---

To clearify: What this answer actually says: Let $\phi(x)$ be a $\{+,e,\in\}$-formula and let $\kappa$ be an ordinal. We cannot prove (in ZFC) that
$$\phi( (\kappa,+,e,\in) ) := \{ \alpha < \kappa \mid (\kappa,+,e,\in) \models \phi(\alpha) \}
$$
contains a cardinal above $\omega$.

On the other hand, let 
$$
\phi(x) = x \in  \omega \vee x = \omega \vee \forall y \colon y = x \vee y \in x
$$

Then $\phi((\omega_1+1; \in)) = \omega+1 \cup \{\omega_1\}$ and thus $\phi(x)$ defines a set of cardinals, that contains an uncountable cardinal. This may seem very strange to you, but what my answer basically comes down to: Above $\omega$, ZFC tells us nothing about *which* ordinals are cardinals... (Even if we restrict our attention to transitive models with "the true" membership relation.)

Comment: Thanks for your post. I lack the knowledge necessary to understanding it but I will keep it in mind and think about it again when I figure I can.

Comment: Well, this approach uses blunt force to show that $(\kappa,+,e,\in)$ may now very little about its cardinals. It's definitely not elegant, but it came to mind and as this question hasn't had any responses yet, I figured that I should share my thoughts.

Comment: Ok I think I get it. 
($\phi(\omega_1 + 1,\in)$ should rather be $\omega \cup \{\omega_1\}$ though)

Comment: Actually no, but I probably should've written it down in a different fashion: $\omega +1 = \omega \cup \{\omega \}$, so $\omega+1  \cup _\{omega_1\}$ consists of all finite ordinals, $\omega$ and $\omega_1$ (nothing more). Sorry if I unintentionally confused you by using ordinal addition instead of unions.

Comment: Oh, there was a typo in my formula. Sorry.

Comment: No problem, this wasn't the important part anyway!
For the record, this question was raised when while trying to prove that an ordinal was a cardinal, I could get plenty of seemingly useless ordinal arithmetic inequalities, so I wondered if this method was bound to fail.

Comment: I do not completely understand part a). It is a bit strange to state like this, since you are changing the cardinal $\kappa$. I would expect that if a structure is said to be absolute between transitive models, then its ingredients are in both models. When you clarify it's also clear that you are changing the universe of the structure.

Comment: @Pedro I'm not sure how to improve my answer if I have to use forcing as a blackbox. But let me provide another example. Let $\kappa = \omega_n$ for some $1 < n < \omega$ and assume that we had a formula $\phi$ s.t. $\{ \omega < \alpha < \kappa \mid (\kappa;+,\cdot,e,\in) \models \phi(\alpha) \} = \{ \omega_1, \ldots, \omega_{n-1} \}$. We then may collapse $\omega_1$ in a way that each $\omega_n$, for $n > 1$ becomes $\omega_{n-1}$ in a generic extension $V[G]$. If we now look at $\{ \omega < \alpha < \kappa \mid (\kappa;+,\cdot,e,\in) \models \phi(\alpha) \}$ in $V[G]$, it still has

Comment: @Pedro $n-1$ elements (this needs some justification, namely that ordinal arithmetic doesn't change), but we now know, that there has to be a non-cardinal in this set (as there are only $n-2$ uncountable cardinals below $\kappa$ in our generic extension). Thus $ZFC$ cannot prove, that our defining formula works.